# How to get PHP array in JQuery without using JSON?

Tags: php, jquery

I need help on how to convert PHP array into JQuery without using JSON.

Here is my PHP Code:

```
 if (intval($data1['ct']) > intval($_GET['current'])) {
    $res['result'] = true;
    $res['current'] = intval($data1['ct']);
  }
  else
  {
    $res['result'] = false;
  }

  exit;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of avoiding JSON?

Comment: Just wanted to try alternative solution

Comment: Then generate XML, but it is silly, because JSON is the most appropriate format for JavaScript in most cases. Even if PHP is supposed to generate HTML, you should adhere some protocol such as `{response: "HTML..", "error": false}`

Comment: do you have another alternative for that?

Comment: you won't get an associated data without using a json or xml.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to make a string for every key-value pair and pass it to jQuery.

But that is not a good practice

My advice is to always use JSON when dealing with this kind of situations

Answer (score 0):

What about echoing the results as json like this:

```
return echo json_encode($res);
```

and catching the results with $.ajax of jquery with option `dataType: "json"` or simply parsing with `JSON.parse(array_from_php)`

Tell me if that works.
Greetings!

Comment: yes I already tried it before and it works. well JSON is the top priority I guess.

Answer (score 0):

server response:`return echo json_encode($res);`

js: get it, can just use it. without `json.parse`.

Comment: just put it inside js variable?